# ValueError: could not convert string to float in panda

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, machine-learning, sklearn-pandas

My code is :

```
 import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_table('train.tsv')

X=data.Phrase
Y=data.Sentiment
from sklearn import cross_validation
X_train,X_test,Y_train,Y_test=cross_validation.train_test_split(X,Y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB
clf = MultinomialNB()
clf.fit(X,Y)
```

I get the error :`ValueError: could not convert string to float:`

What changes can I make that my code works?

Comment: What is `data.info()` ? All data are numeric?

Comment: no
it consists of strings too.
X.phrase has string data.
Y.Sentiment has numeric data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pass in text data into MultinomialNB of scikit-learn as stated in its [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html).

None of the algorithms in scikit-learn works directly with text data. You need to do some preprocessing to get desired output. You'll need to first extract the features from text data using techniques like bagging or tokenizing. Have a look at this [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html) for better understanding.

You also might want to look at using [NLTK](http://www.nltk.org/) for such use cases as yours.

Answer (score 0):

[ValueError when using Multinomial Naive Bayes classifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35098326/valueerror-when-using-multinomial-naive-bayes-classifier/35100661)

You probably should preprocess your data as shown in the answer above.